# Can NN predict the pressure by velocity instead of solving the Poisson equation?

Tags: neural-network, fluid-dynamics

In imcompressible CFD code based on Chorin's projection method, the velocity is divided into 2 parts:

`$\Delta u=\Delta u^*+\Delta u' $`, where `$\Delta u^*=\nu \nabla^2 v+f$`. In classic method, pressure `#p#` would be solved by a Poisson equation, then the `$u'$` would be calculated by its gradient.

In my code, a simple NN model is employed to predict the pressure by $u^*$, and it works approximately. However, the divergence of the velocity `$\nabla \cdot \Delta u$`, which should be zero in the whole flow area, could not keep zero.

I think it must be the problem of my simple NN model, and I am just wondering that can NN predict the velocity directly with the condition `$\nabla \cdot \Delta u = 0$`?

Answer (score 0):

If your neural network does not *learn* to output divergence-free velocity fields, then obviously it will not do so. You could enforce the divergence free condition in the loss function of the neural network to try to achieve this.